# Vue JS | Component transfering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Wanna transfer component as variable.

For example:
We have 3 components: A,B,C.

A.vue

```
<template>
<B>:redirect_object=C</B>
</template>
<script>
import B from "B";
import C from "C";
export default {
    name: "A",
    components: {B,C}
}
```

B.vue

```
...
<script>
export default {
    name: "B",
    props: {
        title: String,
        content: String,
        icon: String,
        redirect_object: Object // This var should contain coming component

    },
    methods: {
        do_redirect: function () {
            if (this.redirect_object)
                this.$store.commit('change_module', this.redirect_object)
        }
    }
}
```

C.vue

```
...
<script>
export default {
    name: "C"
}
```

So. I want transfer C.vue component through A.vue to B.vue into `redirect_object` variable in `props`.

Tried to import C component in A, but I can't transfer it to B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why should you do this? I think it's not a good practice to transfer components like this. The general approach with components is to `import` components in components (parent - child ) and to dynamically load components with `:is` attribute.

[Docs with examples for dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)

Comment: Looks like кастыли, really

Comment: What is your main idea for the code? You should not have `<B>:redirect_object=C</B>` where `C` is a component reference. You should import `<C>` in component `<B>` and register it inside of it.

Comment: Don't worry, it's fine. We all are learning new things everyday.

Best regards,